# View with 2 taxonomy term in url

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, views

I a new Drupal 8 user :) and I have a problem with my view !

The context: I have a content type Car with Brand (Taxonomy term ) and Color (Taxo term)
[image]

I want to know if it's possible to have this url:

```
mywebsite/ => view with all cars 

mywebsite/brand => view with all cars for the brand

mywebsite/brand/color => view with all cars for the brand with the color
```

This is my view

[image]

I don't know if it's possbile but I try :)

Thx for you help 
And see you soon

Comment: Got to the advanced section of your view and add both taxonomy fields to the context filter. Set the path of the view to view_path/%taxonomy_term/%taxonomy_term

Comment: Ok, I add to url view => cars/%taxonomy_term and after I add to contextual filter Content:brand. After I try to past in url cars/bmw but nothin to show in view ! [link to screenshot of my view](https://prnt.sc/fez8um)

Comment: Ok, my fault, here you can only use the term ids. If you like to use the term name, add in the advanced section a relation to the brand field and then add a context filter to taxonomy name. Remove the old context filter and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the path to:

```
cars/%taxonomy_term/%taxonomy_term
```

Then add two relations in the advanced section:

```
Taxonomy term referenced from field_brand
Taxonomy term referenced from field_color
```

Then add two times the following context filter:

```
Name (Taxonomy Term)
```

Select in the first context filter the relationship `field_brand` and in the second context filter the `field_color`:

now it should work as expected.